# Running loop in script in sql plus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am running a script in sql plus, I have a for loop in my script:

```
BEGIN
  FOR count IN 1..100 LOOP
    INSERT INTO CompanyShare VALUES (count, 1, 250);
  END LOOP;
END;

BEGIN
  FOR count IN 101..200 LOOP
    INSERT INTO CompanyShare VALUES (count, 2, 50);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

When I run the script this error came up:

> ORA-06550: line 6, column 1: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN"

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: you missed a `;` at the END of first block. And I would not use `count` as variable name, as it is a sql reserved word.

Comment: Rectified it but still giving me the same error

Comment: add also a `/` as parado says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add `/` after `end;` as below:

```
BEGIN
  FOR count IN 1..100 LOOP
    INSERT INTO CompanyShare VALUES (count, 1, 250);
  END LOOP;
END;
/ --<-- Here
BEGIN
  FOR count IN 101..200 LOOP
    INSERT INTO CompanyShare VALUES (count, 2, 50);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks...Now my script is running

Answer (score 3):

Looking to your logic ,you can even simplify the script based on condition .

```
  BEGIN
  FOR count IN 1..200
   LOOP
    INSERT INTO CompanyShare VALUES (count
                                    ,CASE WHEN count<=100 THEN 1   ELSE 2  END
                                    ,CASE WHEN count<=100 THEN 250 ELSE 50 END
                                    );
   END LOOP;
  END;
  /
```

Answer (score 0):

Semicolon is not there after end .Try this

```
BEGIN
  FOR count IN 1..100 LOOP
   INSERT INTO CompanyShare VALUES (count, 1, 250);
  END LOOP;
END ;   --****
BEGIN
 FOR count IN 101..200 LOOP
  INSERT INTO CompanyShare VALUES (count, 2, 50);
 END LOOP;
END;
```