# How do I iterate over nested rows using a condition in SQL?

Tags: sql, while-loop

I would like to create the equivalent of a FOR loop. I need this in SQL. My goal is to create a new column called Difference which calculates the date difference in days between the end of each row and the beginning of the next row. In essence I need to know if there are any breaks in contracts for each personID. RowID from min to max defines a contract with a specific organisation, such as each new contract with one organisation starts with 1.

My table is:

[image: table]

The SQL code I wrote is:

```
select RowID, start_contract, end_contract from table

open the_cursor

fetch next from the_cursor into @id

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin 
    select
        DATEDIFF(DAY, (select end_contract from table where RowID = @id-1), 
                      (select start_contract from t where RowID = @id)) AS [Difference]

        if (select RowID from t) = 1
            break
        else 
            continue

    fetch next from the_cursor into @id
end

close the_cursor
deallocate the_cursor
```

But I get an error:

> Cursorfetch: The number of variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected columns.

Could anybody help me please?

Thank you so much.

Comment: This post shows how to run a `FOR` loop in SQL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565093/running-loop-in-script-in-sql-plus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select DATEDIFF(DAY, T.end_contract T.start_contract) AS [Difference], T.personID
from table T join table TT on TT.personID=t.personID
where TT.rowID = T.rowID + 1
```

Comment: Thanks, self-join works really well. I had to modify the code to add a join by TT.rowID=T.rowID+1 instead of where, but it did the trick.